# "If condition" error: Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab

I'm new in Matlab and I'm trying to input a matrix and write some "if" condition about it:
(not sure why it doesn't work)

```
function Matrix(X)
A = [-5 -2 3; 4 7 1]

if(X==1)
    A((A>0))=1  %Positive num set to 1
end

if(X==2)
    A(1,A(1,:)<0) = 0 %Negative num in row 1 set to 0
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple `end` at the end of function would solve your problem

Comment: oh yeah I forgot to end the function, but still it says "Error using Matrix (line 4)
Not enough input arguments."

Comment: what did you put in X?

Comment: nothing. I mean, I want X to be my input, so once you print the matrix, you will ask for X. if you type X==1 then you get the result of the first condition, and the same for X==2

Comment: You can't click the run button, you have to pass in the information for X - for instance, from the main command window `Matrix(2)` or `Matrix(1)` will give what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok got it. so how do I change it so when I ask for the matrix in the main command it will print the original matrix and then ask to input X

Comment: That would be X = input("Prompt Message")